# WPF MVVM Light master-detail in TabControl, pass selected item using messages

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, message

I'm very new to WPF MVVM (Light) and I need some help.

What I have is a master-detail scenario, TabControl in the main view, master view (ProductsView) in the first tab and multiple different details views (e.g. DetailsView) in the following tabs.

Depending on the item selected (SelectedProduct) in ProductsView, i want to fetch items in the DetailsView, but not immediately - only when the user clicks the tabitem containing this details view.

So fetching detail data from the database should be somehow deferred to the point when user clicks the appropriate detail tab (he may not click it at all).

Here's my xaml:

```
<!-- Main View -->
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.Views.MainView">
  <TabControl>
    <TabControl.Items>
      <TabItem>
        <views:ProductsView />
      </TabItem>
      <TabItem>
        <views:DetailsView />
      </TabItem>
      <!-- More TabItems with details views -->
    </TabControl.Items>
  </TabControl>
</UserControl>

<!-- Products View -->
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.Views.ProductsView">
  <Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=ProductsVM}">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct}">
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Model.ProductID}" Header="Product ID" />
    </DataGrid>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>

<!-- Details View -->
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.Views.DetailsView">
  <Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=DetailsVM.Details}">
    <StackPanel>
      <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Model.Field1}" />
      <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Model.Field2}" />
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And code:

```
public class ProductsViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<Product> products;
    public ObservableCollection<Product> Products
    {
        get
        {
            return products;
        }
        set
        {   // RaisePropertyChanged
            Set("Products", ref products, value);
        }
    }

    private Product selectedProduct;
    public Product SelectedProduct
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedProduct;
        }
        set
        {   // RaisePropertyChanged and broadcast message of type PropertyChangedMessage<Product>
            Set("SelectedProduct", ref selectedProduct, value, true);
        }
    }

    public ProductsViewModel(IDataService dataService)
    {
        this.dataService = dataService;
        Products = dataService.GetAllProducts();
    }
}

public class DetailsViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private Details details;
    public Details Details
    {
        get
        {
            return details;
        }
        set
        {   // RaisePropertyChanged
            Set("Details", ref details, value);
        }
    }

    public DetailsViewModel(IDataService dataService)
    {
        this.dataService = dataService;
        Messenger.Default.Register<PropertyChangedMessage<Product>>(this, m => Details = dataService.GetDetails(m.NewValue.Model.ProductID));
    }
}
```

Now this works, but after product selection, all the details are fetched immediately in all details tabs.
I've been thinking, maybe when the user clicks a tab in MainView, MainViewModel should send a message with tab index to ProductviewModel and then ProductviewModel should send another message passing SelectedProduct to the DetailsViewModel of the currently requested tabitem based on tab index, which would update it's detail data.

But how would I send message only to the currently requested tabitem/DetailsView based on tab index, not all of them?

And also this roundtripping sounds way too complicated. Can you give me some suggestions?
Or is this totally wrong?
Maybe there is another, simpler and more elegant solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

Typically I would have my `ViewModel` track the `Tabs` and `SelectedTab` as well, and would simply load the current tab in the `SelectedTab` `PropertyChanged` event

Something like this:

```cs
// Not expanding these to full properties with property change 
// notifications for sake of simplicity here
ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase> Tabs;
ViewModelBase SelectedTab;

void MyViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "SelectedTab")
    {
        if (SelectedTab is IDetailsTab)
            ((IDetailsTab)SelectedTab).LoadProduct(SelectedProduct);

            // Or depending on your structure:
            var productsTab = Tabs[0] as ProductsViewModel;
            ((IDetailsTab)SelectedTab).LoadProduct(productsTab.SelectedProduct);
    }
}
```

and your XAML would look like this:

```xml
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTab}">
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ProductsViewModel}">
            <local:ProductsView />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DetailsViewModel}">
            <local:DetailsView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.Resources>
</TabControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the classic pub / sub model.  Something with an event called RequestViewOfProductDetails to be raised when a user clicks a tab control item.  You would set up the publish in the primary view model with something like this:

```
public MasterViewModel()
{
    Messenger.Default.Send<RequestViewOfProductDetails>(_selectedProduct); 
}
```

Then, in your details view model, you would set up the view model to respond to that event:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<RequestViewOfProductDetails>(this, delegate(Product prod) 
{ 
  // fetch details
});
```

And you would set up a messge for each detail type, publishing that specific details event on each selection of a tab item.  Tedious, I know, but that separates all tabs.  Now if it were me, I would do something different.  I would do the requests on background worker threads, so you can avoid this headache of targeting specific tabs.  Once a product is selected, just dispatch getters to fill all your tabs asynchronously and things happen transparently.

Answer (score 0):

When your detail tab selected, refresh data on Tab by this event. Pass with event param selected product.